# Retrieving data from API via FormRequest() from a dynamically populated web page

Tags: python, scrapy, postman

I'm trying to scrape news items populated under a url directory of a news web site.

The page that contains the individual news are displayed here: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi

As scrolled down the page is populated with target information. Seen from the XHR feed, the title of the news and the relative links are populated from an API request to the url of https://t24.com.tr/graphql

Studying the headers and body on Postman, I realized following are the required request info:

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length' : 244
}

body = {
  "query": "{storiesByCategory(first: 12, after: \"WyIyMDE5LTA2LTI2VDA3OjQxOjE1LjAwMFoiXQ==\", category: \"15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi\") {cursors{after,hasNext},results{id,slug,title,image,imageAlt,excerpt,publishedAt,category{slug,name,color}}}}"
}
```

Page with populated info from API
[image: page]

Target items to be scraped in API response body:
[image: page]

I wrote a spider to make a request to the API link with necessary request headers&body.

**My problem**: The spider I wrote crawles constant 400 errors. The Postman request I wrote with the same headers&body gives the json with news items to be scraped. I need to scrape the json with news items to follow links contained in them

Scrapy logs

```
    2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: erdo)
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) - [GCC 9.3.0], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.13.0-28-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'erdo',
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'erdo.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['erdo.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36'}
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: cbfda52138ef1cdc
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-02-16 15:02:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi> (referer: None)
2022-02-16 15:02:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/21)
2022-02-16 15:02:09 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/20)
2022-02-16 15:02:15 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/19)
2022-02-16 15:02:23 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/18)
2022-02-16 15:02:30 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/17)
2022-02-16 15:02:36 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/16)
2022-02-16 15:02:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/15)
2022-02-16 15:02:48 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:02:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/14)
2022-02-16 15:02:55 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/13)
2022-02-16 15:03:02 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 10 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-02-16 15:03:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/12)
2022-02-16 15:03:08 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/11)
2022-02-16 15:03:12 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/10)
2022-02-16 15:03:19 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/9)
2022-02-16 15:03:25 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/8)
2022-02-16 15:03:31 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/7)
2022-02-16 15:03:38 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/6)
2022-02-16 15:03:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/5)
2022-02-16 15:03:48 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:03:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/4)
2022-02-16 15:03:55 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:04:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/3)
2022-02-16 15:04:01 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:04:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 20 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-02-16 15:04:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/2)
2022-02-16 15:04:08 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:04:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://t24.com.tr/graphql> (referer: https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi/1)
2022-02-16 15:04:12 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://t24.com.tr/graphql>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2022-02-16 15:04:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-02-16 15:04:12 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 15127,
 'downloader/request_count': 22,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 21,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 46145,
 'downloader/response_count': 22,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 21,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 129.98732,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 16, 12, 4, 12, 326876),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 226813,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 21,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/400': 21,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 22,
 'log_count/INFO': 33,
 'memusage/max': 64782336,
 'memusage/startup': 61345792,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 22,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 22,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 22,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 22,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 22,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 16, 12, 2, 2, 339556)}
2022-02-16 15:04:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is my Spider's code

```
from ast import For
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request
import json
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TarapSpider(Spider):
    name = 't24_15t'
    allowed_domains = ['t24.com.tr']
    start_urls   = [ 'https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi' ]
    urll= "https://t24.com.tr/graphql"

headerz = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length' : 244
}
def parse(self, response):
    counter = 0
    check =True
    while check == True:
        counter +=1 
        referer = f"{self.root_link}/{str(counter)}"
        curr_header = self.headerz
        curr_header["referer"] = (referer)
        
        yield FormRequest(
            url = self.urll,
            callback=self.tarse,
            method="POST",
            headers=curr_header,
            formdata= json.loads(r"""{"query":"{storiesByCategory(first: 12, after: \"WyIyMDE5LTA2LTI2VDA3OjQxOjE1LjAwMFoiXQ==\", category: \"15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi\") {cursors{after,hasNext},results{id,slug,title,image,imageAlt,excerpt,publishedAt,category{slug,name,color}}}}"}"""),dont_filter=True
            )
        if counter == 21:
            check = False
        

def tarse(self, response):

    print(response.body)
```

Comment: Those are definitely not the correct headers, also you NEVER want to add `content-length`.

Comment: Why not? They work in Postman but only for the first 5 query. No matter how I change the referrer incrementally, I receive the same 60 results again and again.

Comment: Because I checked the headers and some important stuff are missing. The reason you're getting the same results is because `WyIyMDE5LTA2LTI2VDA3OjQxOjE1LjAwMFoiXQ==` is a time stamp (search for base64 decode and see for yourself), every time you scroll down to a new page the timestamp that it sends is decreasing by 6 months, and you send the same one over and over again.

Comment: Interesting. What data type is it the key value of 'query' key of the body? I couldn't a figure a way to imitate it. I also still couldn't understand the exact corelation between news items populated and the 'after' key's value that you mentioned.

When I decoded these with base64, I saw that values like ["2019-06-26T07:41:15.000Z"] and ["2018-12-26T16:33:23.000Z"]. Can you give me some insights on how I suck out the rest of the news items? Writing a new fstring with decoding for each request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the results are correct.

What I did:

1. Set the base date.
2. Every iteration subtract 1 month from the date (it's just a guess I'm really sure where to get this from, so check if it yields correct results).
3. Format the payload with the date.
4. Create a scrapy request with the payload as the body.
5. Added custom settings to prevent blocking.
6. Added the headers as they appear in the browser.

What you can do (only if you want to, it's not a must):

1. Check the results for `has next` so you know when to stop.
2. Instead of a loop make the function go to the next page (what I described in 1), basically the `callback` will be the same function so it will go by the order of pages and stop when it will reach stopping condition.

The code:

```py
import datetime
from ast import For
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request
import json
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import base64


class TarapSpider(Spider):
    name = 't24_15t'
    allowed_domains = ['t24.com.tr']
    start_urls = [ 'https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi' ]

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 4
    }

    url = "https://t24.com.tr/graphql"
    root_link = 'https://t24.com.tr/haber/15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi'
    form_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-06-26 07:41:15.000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "t24.com.tr",
        "Origin": "https://t24.com.tr",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
        "X-KL-Ajax-Request": "Ajax_Request"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for counter in range(1, 22):
            referer = f"{self.root_link}/{str(counter)}"
            curr_header = self.headers
            curr_header["referer"] = referer
            form_ts = f"[\"{self.form_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]}Z\"]"
            form_ts = base64.b64encode(form_ts.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
            payload = {"query":"{storiesByCategory(first: 12, after: \"" + form_ts + "\", category: \"15-temmuz-darbe-girisimi\") {cursors{after,hasNext},results{id,slug,title,image,imageAlt,excerpt,publishedAt,category{slug,name,color}}}}"}

            self.form_date = self.form_date - relativedelta(months=1)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.url,
                callback=self.tarse,
                method="POST",
                headers=curr_header,
                body=json.dumps(payload),
                dont_filter=True
            )

    def tarse(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```